# Floating point test assertion - why do these "identical" arrays fail?

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm using **assertSame()** in PHPUnit to compare a database result with expected values. The results are floating point numbers.

PHPUnit returns this message (but I can't spot any differences):

```
Failed asserting that Array (
    '1_1' => 11.111111111111
    '1_2' => 33.333333333333
    '1_3' => 55.555555555556
    '1_4' => 0.0
    '1_5' => null
    '1_total' => 100.0
) is identical to Array (
    '1_1' => 11.111111111111
    '1_2' => 33.333333333333
    '1_3' => 55.555555555556
    '1_4' => 0.0
    '1_5' => null
    '1_total' => 100.0
)
```

Why is this failing and what is the correct way to compare an arrays of floating point values?

Comment: Can you add phpunit console result output screenshot here please.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

assertEquals has a $floating_delta argument for this type of cases:

```
$this->assertEquals($expected_array, $actual_array, '', 0.00001);
```

[PHPUnit docs](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.assertions.assertEquals)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is almost certainly floating point precision.  In the print_r, only so many digits are shown.  If all significant bits were displayed, the situation is probably something like this:

```
Failed asserting that Array (
    '1_1' => 11.1111111111110347
    '1_2' => 33.3333333333331678
    '1_3' => 55.5555555555562773
    '1_4' => 0.0
    '1_5' => null
    '1_total' => 100.0
) is identical to Array (
    '1_1' => 11.1111111111110346
    '1_2' => 33.3333333333331679
    '1_3' => 55.5555555555562771
    '1_4' => 0.0
    '1_5' => null
    '1_total' => 100.0
)
```

Every floating point comparison—especially equality—must consider the lack of infinite precision.

```
if ($var == 0.005)     /* just plain wrong! */

if (abs ($var, 0.005) < 0.001)    /*  more correct  */

if (abs ($var, 0.005) < 0.0001)    /* maybe more correct, depending on application */

if (abs ($var, 0.005) < 0.0000001)    /* possibly more appropriate */
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless anyone has a better suggestion, I will assume this is a floating point precision error, and follow the PHP manual advice: **[do not compare floating point numbers directly for equality](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)**.

So my own solution is to round the array values before comparison.